# Define $f:[-4,0]→\mathbb R$ by $f(x)$=$\frac{2x^2-18}{x+3}$ for $x\neq-3$, $f(-3)=-12$ Show $f$ is continuous at $-3$.

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f:[-4,0]→\mathbb R$ by $f(x)$=$\frac{2x^2-18}{x+3}$ for $x\neq-3$, $f(-3)=-12$ Show $f$ is continuous at $-3$.

So, since we know $-3$ is an accumulation point of $[-4,0]$, is it possible to use our theorem that states:

Let $f:D→\mathbb R$ with $x_o$ an accumulation point of $D$. Then $f$ has a limit at $x_o$ iff each sequence $\{{x_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $x_o$ with $x_n\in D$ and $x_n\neq x_o$ for all $n$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges.

Then, with that theorem we can then use another theorem about continuity that states:

Let $f:D→\mathbb R$ with $x_o\in D$ and $x_o$ an accumulation point of $D$. Then the following are equivalent:

1). $f$ is continous at $x_o$.

2). $f$ has a limit at $x_o$ and $\lim_{x→x_o}f(x)=f(x_o)$.

3). For every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $x_o$ with $x_n\in D$ for each $n$, $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f(x_o)$.

Only to show that 3). holds true because of the first theorem and if 3). holds, then 1). holds and so $f$ is continuous at $-3$?

Or maybe I'm going about it all wrong, not sure. Help?

Comment: You can make it a lot simpler by observing that $f(x)=2x-6$ for $x \neq -3$ and $f(-3)=-12$ which combines to $f(x)=2x-6$ for all $x$.

Comment: Is it just supposed to be that simple? I noticed that-- but I wasn't sure if that's where it ends. We're barely getting into continuity(in fact we've only proved this single theorem on continuity, that's the extent of it for now), and so I wasn't sure how simple I can make things.

Comment: I am sure any reasonable teacher would accept a proof that makes a little algebraic manipulation before proving continuity.

Answer (score 1):

We know that, for $x\neq -3$
$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{2x ^2-18}{x+3}&=&2\frac{x ^2-9}{x+3}\\ 
\\
&=&2\frac{(x -3)(x+3)}{x+3}
\\ 
\\
&=&2(x -3)
\end{matrix}$$

Then by sending $x$ to $-3$, we get : $\lim_{x\rightarrow -3} f(x)=-12$

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital;s Rule
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{2x^2-18}{x+3}=\lim _{x \rightarrow -3} 4x=-12=f(-3). $$
So $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=-3$.